# Use VB.net to create scheduled task that has "Run with highest privileges" enabled

Tags: vb.net, task, scheduler

I have a function that creates a task but I can not get the checkbox enabled for "Run with highest privileges". I commenrted out the line for Runlevel as it was giving an error.
Below is the funcion.

```
Sub VaultProFullBackupTask()
    Using tService As New TaskService()

        Dim tDefinition As TaskDefinition = tService.NewTask
        tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Vault Pro Full Backup"
        tDefinition.Settings.Priority = ProcessPriorityClass.AboveNormal
        'tDefinition.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest

        Dim tTrigger As New WeeklyTrigger()
        tTrigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2)
        tTrigger.DaysOfWeek = DaysOfTheWeek.Monday
        tTrigger.WeeksInterval = 1

        tDefinition.Triggers.Add(tTrigger)

        tDefinition.Actions.Add(New ExecAction(VaultScriptFolder & "\VaultBackupFull.bat"))

        tService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Vault Pro Full Backup", tDefinition)

    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Looking at the docs for [Principal.RunLevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/principal-runlevel) there are a couple exclusions in the remarks.  Is any of that possibly your problem?

Comment: Thank you for the info. I am running the program under my local admin account which from what I read, ignores the runlevel setting. Does this explain why I am getting an error?